# Difficult to paraphrase a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, relative-clauses, paraphrasing

I am not a native speaker. I find a sentence from a passage like:

> The strong economic growth expected in countries which are candidates for entry to the EU will also increase transport flows, in particular, road haulage traffic.

I convert this sentence into two simple sentences to understand their meaning. 1st one is:

> 1. The strong economic growth expected in countries.

2nd one is:

> 2. Countries are candidates for entry to the EU will also increase transport flows.

However, I cannot separate the *comma* portion. In addition, I cannot understand the meaning of my 2nd simple sentence. I am confused by the word **candidates**.

Can anyone help me to paraphrase the sentence properly?

Answer (score 2):

Your two simple sentences are not correct, unfortunately.  I would split it into two sentences like this:

> Countries which are candidates for entry to the EU are expected to show strong economic growth.  This [economic growth] will also increase transport flows, in particular road haulage traffic.

Or perhaps:

> Strong economic growth is expected in countries which are candidates for entry to the EU. This [economic growth] will also increase transport flows, in particular road haulage traffic.

**Candidates** are people (or organisations, countries, etc) which are being considered for something (such as a job vacancy, political office, or in this case EU membership).

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

The word **candidates** refers to nominated entities. In this case, the countries are the candidates. They are being considered to be in the EU.

---

A better answer would be:
*Being candidates for entry to the EU, countries expecting strong economic growth will increase transport flows, particularly, road haulage traffic.*